# How to loop through a list and also ignore specific item in the list based on condition before appending to string builder?

Tags: c#

The following code is simply a blue print of something I am working on.

I need to add several items to a `List`, then append the `List` to a `StringBuilder`.
The problem is I need to add bullets to the list which I have done below.

However, I do not want to add a bullet to the last item in the list but I am unsure how to exclude it.

As you can see I ignore any item in the List that is null as indicated below. I need to include the last item but without the bullet.

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int bullet = 1;
    StringBuilder Assembler = new StringBuilder();
    List<string> myList = new List<string>();

    //THIS NULL IS INTENTIONAL
    myList.Add(null);

    myList.Add("Oranges");
    myList.Add("Banana");
    myList.Add("This is a Comment and I do not want to add a bullet to it.");

    foreach (string item in myList)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            Assembler.AppendLine("(" + bullet++ + ") " + item);
        }
    }

    Console.Write(Assembler.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! I wish I could mark all as answers. I know this question sounds simple but threr are some nice ideas mentioned below, especially the `StartsWith`. and the bool class. Thanks everyone, I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == myList.Count - 1)
                Assembler.AppendLine(myList[i]);
            else
            {
                if (myList[i] != null)
                    Assembler.AppendLine("(" + bullet++ + ") " + myList[i]);
            }

        }
```

Try this. :)

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly

```
 class bullet
        {
            public bool needToBeAdded;
            public string name;
            public bullet(string ex_name, bool ex_add) {
                needToBeAdded = ex_add;
                name = ex_name;
            }
        }

...

            int bullet = 1;
            StringBuilder Assembler = new StringBuilder();
            List<bullet> myList = new List<bullet>();

            //THIS NULL IS INTENTIONAL
            myList.Add(null);

            myList.Add(new bullet("Oranges",true));
            myList.Add(new bullet("Banana", true));
            myList.Add(new bullet("This is a Comment and I do not want to add a bullet to it.", false));

            foreach (bullet item in myList)            
                if (item != null&&item.needToBeAdded)                
                    Assembler.AppendLine("(" + bullet++ + ") " + item.name);
            Console.Write(Assembler.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check index of item from List.

```
if (myList.IndexOf(item) != myList.Count - 1)
   Assembler.AppendLine("(" + bullet++ + ") " + item);
else
   Assembler.AppendLine("(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use for instead and go upto one less than the total count:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myList.Count - 1; i++) {                    

     string item  = myList[i];

     if (item != null) {

        Assembler.AppendLine("(" + bullet++ + ") " + item);
     } 
}

// And for the last item

Assembler.AppendLine(myList[myList.Count - 1]);
```

---

Comment: Just an FYI: The above does not append the last item. I still need to append the last item just without a bullet. Thank you so much.

Comment: Got it. Have a look at the change.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `for` instead of `foreach`:

```
var countMinusOne = myList.Count - 1;
for(int i = 0; i < countMinusOne; i++)
    if(myList[i] != null)
        Assembler.AppendLine("(" + bullet++ + ") " + myList[i]);
Assembler.AppendLine(myList[countMinusOne]);
```

Or LINQ with `String.Join`:

```
var countMinusOne = myList.Count - 1;
var result
    = String.Join(
        Environment.NewLine, 
        myList.Where((x, i) => x != null && i != countMinusOne)
              .Select((x, i) => "(" + (i + 1) + ") " + x))
                  + Environment.NewLine + myList.Last();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another alternative:

```
...
var lastItem = myList.LastOrDefault();

foreach (string item in myList)
{
  if (item == null) continue;

  if (item == lastItem) 
    Assembler.AppendLine(item);
  else
    Assembler.AppendLine("(" + bullet++ + ") " + item);
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by adding some kind of special character in the beginning of those strings in the list which are not meant to have a bullet. And then later remove it while adding it to the substring. Hope this helps for you.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int bullet = 1;
        StringBuilder Assembler = new StringBuilder();
        List<string> myList = new List<string>();

        //THIS NULL IS INTENTIONAL
        myList.Add(null);

        myList.Add("Oranges");
        myList.Add("Banana");
        // Purposefully adding an extra character in the beginning of the string to
        // differtiate it.
        myList.Add("`" + "This is a Comment and I do not want to add a bullet to it.");

        foreach (string item in myList)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                if (item.StartsWith("`"))
                {
                    Assembler.AppendLine(item.Substring(1, item.Length - 1));
                }
                else
                {
                    Assembler.AppendLine("(" + bullet++ + ") " + item);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.Write(Assembler.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```